# How can I call different web pages with query strings?

Tags: html, asp.net, iis, query-string

I have the following problem. I downloaded a web page with the wayback machine downloader. The wayback machine downloader saves the query strings with %3f because question marks are not allowed in Windows Explorer. For example, when I go to the splash.aspx?page=3 page, nothing happens except that for each value after the ?, the same page appears. How can I assign different pages with the query strings?
Btw: I use IIS for hosting.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the downloader creates a static copy of the site. There won't be any server-side processing. Multi-page processing requires that.

Assuming that the wayback machine actually iterated through all the pages, you will need a different downloading tool that can find them all, creating static versions of each page and rewriting the links for each, since the wayback machine downloader doesn't know how to do paging itself.

---

But really, stepping back, I think what you're trying to do is the problem. Wayback Machine is for creating snapshots of sites at a point in time. It's goal is not to backup and restore the backend functionality. (Which it can't do, even if it wanted to, since it doesn't have access to the backend of every site on the internet.)

You didn't specify what your final end goal is, but my guess is that while the wayback machine might be able to be used to scrape the data, you'll have to write your own server code and website if you want to redeliver it again. (And assuming you have the rights to do so.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!

I read from another forum that you can use the Url Rewrite addon in IIS to remove the query string and redirect it to a simpler url. Would that work?

Comment: @tm3241 That might be able to get it to return the first page. But the query parameter is normally necessary to figure out which page. But since you don't have the server side of the code, nor the other pages' data, it won't help you page through everything.

Comment: I have the files for the other pages, of course.

Comment: @tm3241 If you use iis url rewriting, you can redirect to different web pages through query strings, but this is fixed and cannot be done dynamically.

Comment: How do I configure url rewrite?